# Filesteam from Iage(from website)

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, filestream

Somehow, my filestream changed its mind about allowing me to download images from a website.

```
string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"{2}Content-Type: {3}{2}{2}";
string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, fileParameterName, filePath, newLine, contentType);

byte[] headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
requestStream.Write(headerBytes, 0, headerBytes.Length);

using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4097];
    Int32 bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    while ((bytesRead > 0))
    {
        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

`using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))`

is the line that is causing the problems. The filepath is not valid apparently. The code worked yesterday but today it errors out. an example filepath Im using is

http://www.images.jpg

After some research it looks like the filepath cannot contain ':'.

Does anyone have a solution for writing an image into a filestream, or equivalant, for use with an http webrequest?

Comment: What exactly is 'chokes'? exception? Have you tried `try`, `catch` block for solving your problem?

Comment: The fath is the filepath name of http:\\www.image.jpg is no good for a filepath name. It cannot contain a ':' apparently.